# how to compare two fields defined in schema($gte) in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Food Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const foodSchema = new Schema({
  foodName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  offerPrice:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  shopName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Food', foodSchema);
```

how to select the foods where food.price>food.offerPrice
"price": { $gt: 100} this selects the food where the price is greater than 100 but i need to compare two values defined in schema
"price": { $gt:offerPrice } is invalid syntax

Comment: look the example with `$expr` by mongodb https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#examples

Comment: yes it works,thank you very much. add the answer i will mark it as answer

Comment: No need to answer because similar question is already available.

Comment: ok i have seen that too.